# Updating a Mysql database from XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml

I am using the following php code to load data from an xml file to insert in Mysql, I want to update this rss feed whenever new articles are in this website.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("rss") ;

$feeds = array('http://mywebsite.com/index.php?format=feed&type=rss');
foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
$date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008




 echo '<style type="text/css">.style1 { direction: rtl;</style><p class="style1">';
 echo $item->pubDate;  
 echo '<br><a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a><br>';
 echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div><br><br><br><hr><br>';
 echo '<div>' . $item->content . '</div><br><br><br>';             
 echo '</p>';




mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss_feeds (id, title, description, link, category, pubdate,  facebook_pub, website) 
VALUES (
    '', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description=htmlspecialchars(trim($item->description)))."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->link)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->category)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->pubDate)."',
    'No', 
    'almourassel.com')");    
    }
    }
    ?>
```

However, when I load this script, it re'inserts the previously added data. How can I just update the new articles.

I think the script should add the new items until it meets the las added element in the table by comparing the Pubdate.

Comment: Hi everybody, I found that the best solution for the question here is the use of INSERT IGNORE INTO feeds as it is very fast and just update the missing data. Important to note that I changed the title column to unique, Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also write two different queries ,one for deleting the existing data of tables and then hit your insert query.
or you can use replace into command of mysql.
i have done it before in a very simple way,see:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `wp_property`") or die(mysql_error());   
echo "Old data deleted !: <br /><br />";
$xmls = simplexml_load_file('my_file_location.xml');
foreach($xmls->Property as $xml)
{
$ID = $xml->ID;  
$ManagementCompanyID = $xml->ManagementCompanyID;
$MarketingName = $xml->MarketingName;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_property` SET`ID`='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($ID))."',   `ManagementCompanyID`='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($ManagementCompanyID))."', `MarketingName`='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($MarketingName))."'";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

}
echo "New Records added successfully ! <br /><br />";
```

hope it will help you.
happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. that's very helpful. But please can you tell me how to mofidy my code inorder to get the items from the xml file published only that day?

Comment: @NizarBarkallah you can parse xml file in different ways.this is the simplest one. i am not getting your point correctly, sorry for that, but if you want to delete the previous data and insert new one daily,then you have to use "cronjob" for that. also if it is helpful for you, please give me vote:)

Comment: Hi, I found that the best solution for the question here is the use of INSERT IGNORE INTO feeds as it is very fast and just update the missing data. Important to note that I changed the title column to unique, Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use the MySQL `replace into` command

`REPLACE INTO table_name(column_name1,column_name2,…) VALUES(value1,value2,…)`

MySQL REPLACE statement is a MySQL extension to SQL standard. MySQL REPLACE works like the INSERT statement with the following rules:

- If the record being inserting does not exist, MySQL REPLACE will insert a new record.
- If the record being inserting exists, MySQL REPLACE will delete the old record first and then insert a new record with new values.

Basically all you have to do is replace `INSERT INTO` by `REPLACE INTO` in the SQL statement.

However if you have `auto-increment primary keys`, for example, `replace into` might not be a good idea, since it deletes and inserts records, new PK ids will be created for same records thereby causing problems for FK constraints..

Another option is to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` this will again check for duplicates on unique key fields. If you can be sure that pubdate will be unique for each article, this syntax can be used instead of `replace into`

Or you could go the traditional route where you do a `select from table where db_pubdate = rss_pubdate` and if there are no matching records you do an `insert into table`

Comment: Thanks a lot Raidenace for this answer, it is very useful. But doesn't this method take a lot of time whike executing if the website contains many articles ? Probably, It would better look for and insert the articles of that very day.

Comment: Internally, what this method does is check for existence of a record as well. There might be performance degradation, but I think only if the record set is really huge. Of course you can do a `select where db_pubdate = rss_pubdate` and then only do inserts for those records which does not have a match, but this will mean running a `select - where` for every record that you fetched in the rss feed. Having said that, you could do a simple benchmark to see what is the difference in speed. The `replace into` is a convenience method for merging records into database. Anyways, all the best!

Comment: When I implemented this method, it always added all the articles since the id field will always be different. Any help please

Comment: oh my, if you have `auto_increment` fields then using a `replace into` might not be a very good idea - because as stated, it `deletes and inserts` whereby creating new PK ids and breaking existing FK relationships, if any. You could use a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but considering what you are trying to achieve here, I think doing a `select - where` and then inserting if matching pupdate does not exist seems the best solution. Sorry that replace into doesnt seem to be the best way forward here. I will update answer to reflect that!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I am thinking of the second solution as better. Can I contact you directly through skkype ou msn right now so that you help me solve this problem if you don't mind of course ? My skype is nizar.b78 .Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am on the road :) You can check out the MYSQL docs for the syntax of `on duplicate key update`. Let me know how it goes. I will check this spot later!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll post the solution as soon as I get it working

Comment: Hi, I found that the best solution for the question here is the use of INSERT IGNORE INTO feeds as it is very fast and just update the missing data. Important to note that I changed the title column to unique, Thanks for all of you.